# exception handling In Qt or any C Application

Tags: exception, try-catch

I want to throw exception handling in C instead of crashing my application in C or Qt platform .
Example am taking below code

```
 int main() 
{ 
   char *str;  
   
   /* Stored in read only part of data segment */
   str = "GfG";      
   
   /* Problem:  trying to modify read only memory */
   *(str+1) = 'n';  
   return 0; 
}
```

which gives a Segmentation fault (core dumped) when execute .

By using try catch ,How can Hanlde the exception i.e My Application doesn't crash finally .

Thanking you in advance .